# Connect Serial Port through COM port or USB adapter (different models)

Tags: linux, serial-port, ttyusb

I use a program where I need to specify a COM port.  Can I connect via COM port (/dev/ttyS0) or through different models of USB-RS232 adapters (on /dev/ttyUSB0), configured so they always bind to the same port?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Do just want to configure "a program" to always use for example /dev/ttyS0  or do you need to ensure that /dev/ttyUSB0 is always the same "USB-to-Serial" Adaptor, regardless of Reboots?

Also: if you use a "standard" programm which is known in the unix / linux world, please let us know which one.

Comment: I need to make sure that whether I connect it through the COM port directly or through the USB Adapter, it is always /dev/ttyS0